# What differentiates a manager from a team leader?

Tags: team, manager, leadership

What differentiates a manager from a team leader (TL)? What is expected of a manager as opposed to a team leader?

Comment: By manager, do you mean project manager, functional manager or just a generic manager in the organization?

Comment: In my experience, "manager" means someone who handles the interface between the team and the rest of the business at large -- personnel issues, performance evaluations, making sure all the right paperwork gets done, and passing policy/direction-setting directives down from above. The team leader is the person who makes sure that the chunk of work that they're responsible for gets done well and on time -- dividing up the task and making sure appropriate people take appropriate chunks of it, tracking their progress, clearing _technical_ issues out of the way, interfacing to peer teams.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably impossible to answer because it generally depends heavily on the specifics of the organization.  What one company calls a "team lead" another company might call a "manager" while other organizations may not make any sort of distinction between the two.

Broadly, though, if an organization makes a distinction between the two roles, it is likely that a "team lead" would be someone that spends part of their time doing the same thing that members of the team are doing and part of their time doing management tasks while a "manager" would be someone that no longer spends a significant fraction of their time doing the same things that the members of their team are doing in order to focus almost exclusively on management tasks.  A "team lead" probably doesn't have HR responsibility for the members of the team (so the "team lead" probably doesn't do annual performance reviews, doesn't have responsibility for hiring and firing, etc.) while a "manager" probably does.

As I said initially, though, the exact parameters are likely to vary from one organization to another.  There is no guarantee that one organization's "manager" isn't going to be spending a significant amount of time doing the same work their team is responsible for.  And it's entirely possible that another organization's "team lead" is going to be responsible for hiring and firing.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that a Team Lead is still "hands on" to a large degree. Whereas a manager tends to be completely "hands off".

Comment: That is exactly how it in my current workplace. The Team Leader is sort of an honorific for the person who makes all the technical decisions, while the "real" Manager makes all staffing decisions and budget approvals, plus larger scale statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Team leader tends to be hands on, supervisory and is generally given a task (whether that's micro or macro) for his team to achieve in x time. They tend to do some of the work themselves, delegate the rest to others, then keep track of the team to ensure the work gets done by reallocating resource as needed.

A manager tends to be more hands off and strategic - they will usually delegate the tasks to teams rather than parcelling out the work individually. They tend to be less involved in the day to day activities of the individuals they are managing, and focus more on the bigger picture

Of course as with anything there's a huge amount of fuzziness here - some companies use one or other term exclusively, and all managers get involved to some extent, while all team leaders have to be strategic to some extent

If you think of team leader as another name for a low end manager (as an attempt to delineate between supervisory and strategic management) that can sometimes help - and allows you to remember that high and low level managers tend to have a lot of crossover in role, scope and behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Both are titles, so they can mean anything. The same title can even mean different things within the same company.

That aside, usually a team lead is primus inter pares. The team lead is the title of someone leading a team while being part of the team.

A manager just manages something. A manager doesn't need to manage people (e.g. office manager). A manager that leads a team doesn't need to be part of that team. A manager can manage people that are in different teams.

A team lead can almost always be considered to be a manager, but the same is not true the other way around.